# Android Manifest intent-filter exclude categories

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

**Update** Turns out that this question is wrong, as it refers to something that is not happening. Nevertheless the comments contain stuff that may help developers that may think they do have this problem. To the mods, if you think this should be closed/deleted, feel free to do so.

---

I want an activity to receive requests to handle intents of action type `android.intent.action.CHOOSER`, but only if they are not `android.intent.category.OPENABLE`.

Actually, I want to handle action type `android.intent.action.CHOOSER` where `category==null` (or `data==null` would work as well), but there's no such category in the manifest strings to set this explicitly, this is why I have to use `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1000">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" android:exclude="true">
</intent-filter>
```

or even better

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1000">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.NULL">
</intent-filter>
```

What I want to do is to solve the problem that if a `android.intent.action.CHOOSER` with `android.intent.category.OPENABLE` comes up, which very likely is a reaction to a call to `startActivityForResult`, to not need to respond with a

```
Intent iResponse = new Intent();
iResponse.setData(SOMEDATA);
setResult(RESULT_OK, iResponse);
finish();
```

because that would mean that I have to implement the functionality that generates `SOMEDATA`, since I can't rely/proxy that `startActivityForResult` to the framework.

Comment: There are plenty of `startActivityForResult()` requests that do not involve `CATEGORY_OPENABLE`. `ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`,  `ACTION_INSERT`, `ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT`, `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`, `ACTION_PASTE`, `ACTION_PICK`, `ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY`, `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT`, and `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` are a few, just based on the ones defined on `Intent`. What you want (negative filtering) is not possible, but it also would not be a solution to your underlying problem (trying to avoid `startActivityForResult()`).

Comment: I'm aware of this, that is why I would prefer  a NULL filter. But all the `ACTION_` don't apply because this is only on `ACTION_CHOOSER`. I really need a solution to this problem.

Comment: "But all the ACTION_ don't apply because this is only on ACTION_CHOOSER" -- sure it does. If you read [the documentation for `ACTION_CHOOSER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER), it says that the output (i.e., what result goes into `setResult()`) "Depends on the protocol of EXTRA_INTENT". `EXTRA_INTENT` is the `Intent` that triggered the chooser, where the user is choosing a matching activity. So, whether the invoking activity used `startActivityForResult()` is based on what winds up in your `EXTRA_INTENT`, and *that* can be any `Intent` action.

Comment: `ACTION_CHOOSER` should never have `CATEGORY_OPENABLE`, or a `Uri` ("No data should be specified" in the docs for the latter). The underlying `Intent` might (i.e., the one in `EXTRA_INTENT`). Hence, I am unclear as to why you are worrying about `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` on your `ACTION_CHOOSER` `<intent-filter>`. Perhaps you might want to post a [mcve] demonstrating that there is a scenario where `ACTION_CHOOSER` is invoked with `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` and what problems that causes.

Comment: I can do all of those. I can create shortcuts, install packages, copy / paste, all of that. Because it doesn't touch my app, since it only listens to `ACTION_CHOOSER` and `ACTION_SEND`. With `ACTION_CHOOSER` I take care of analyzing the `EXTRA_INTENT`, because an `ACTION_SEND` may be in there. The only problem I have is when the `EXTRA_INTENT` is a `android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT`. Oh man. I just noticed that I can't write a manifest filter for it, as the category is in this inner intent.

Comment: "ACTION_CHOOSER should never have CATEGORY_OPENABLE" you're right, I just noticed this. It is in the `EXTRA_INTENT`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CommonsWare Done! I take the `EXTRA_INTENT` that has the `CATEGORY_OPENABLE`, and I add the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` to it and call `startActivity` on it. The framework will then send the result back to the original sender and frees me from calling (and handling the result from) `startActivityForResult`. Yay!